# Eloquent nested WHERE statement

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

For an online competition with the goal of photographing certain objects I've got **users** uploading **pictures** of **objects**, where the objects have a **category** and a **subcategory**.

A user's dashboard should look something like this:

```
  ------------------------------------------------ 
  |                Category                      |  
  ------------------------------------------------  
  |   -----------------------------------------  |
  |   | Subcat.          |  Subcat.           |  |
  |   |------------------|--------------------|  |
  |   |Object1 | Object2 | Object1 | Object2  |  |
  |   |------------------|--------------------|  |
  |   |  Pic1  |  Pic1   | Pic1    | Pic1     |  |
  |   |  Pic2  |  Pic2   | Pic2    | Pic2     |  |
  |   ----------------------------------------   |
  |                                              |
  ------------------------------------------------
```

In order to be able to output the pictures in the appropriate loop, I installed *hasMany* relationships between the models. So I can get an object with a convenient hierarchy by

```
$userPics = Category::with(['subcats','subcats.objects','subcats.objects.pics'])->get();
```

QUESTION:

For the dashboard of course I only want the images from a certain user: the **Pictures** model contains a **user_id** field. I could get the user's pictures directly: `Pictures::where('user_id',$user->id)->get();`, but then I don't have the structure in the object to create the desired view shown above.

How can I do something like this:

```
$userPics = Category::with([...])->where('user_id',$user->id)->get();
```

Many thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get categories with pictures that belong to specified user, so you do this (a bit verbose):

```
Category::with(['subcats', 'subcats.objects' => function ($q) use ($user) {
        $q->with(['pictures' => function ($q) use ($user) {
            $q->where('user_id', $user->id);
        }]);
    }])
    ->whereHas('subcats', function ($q) use ($user) {
        $q->whereHas('objects', function ($q) use ($user) {
            $q->whereHas('pictures', function ($q) use ($user) {
                $q->where('user_id', $user->id);
            });
        });
    })
    ->get();
```

You need to use nested `with()` closures here, because you can load more than two levels of relationship with using dot notation.

If you don't need to load pictures and subcategories data, just remove `with()` part.

If you also want to filter subcategories, add a closure to `with()` for `subcats`.

Comment: Wow, amazingly fast answer! Yes, this indeed filters only the user's pictures.

However, all of the categories / subcategories / objects are still in the output. I'd like to have only those where the user has a picture. How would I achieve that?

Comment: @MichielvanNesselrooij updated, please look. If you don't need to load pictures and subcategories data, just remove `with()` part and you'll get only categories which have pictures of specified user.

Comment: Fantastic. In fact I will also need the output of the query without 'whereHas', so your answer serves a double purpose. I've awarded you the answer. Thank you.