# How to get a model relationship only if a given condition on parent model is met

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a posts model, I need to get posts only from the channels the user belongs to if the channel is private or otherwise get all the posts from all the channels. Public channel can be viewed by everyone and every post belongs to a channel

Currently from the code i have, I'm getting posts from only private channels the user have joined. I can't get the posts from the public channels too. $this->model references to Post model

```php
$this->model->whereHas('channel', function ($q) use ($user){
                 $q->where('is_hidden', false)
                    ->where('is_private', false)
                    ->whereHas('members', function ($q) use ($user){
                        $q->where('user_id', $user->id);
                    }
                );
            });
```

I should be getting all the posts from the private channels the user belongs to and all posts from the public channels

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after some trials by using `->where(function($query){})`

```php
$this->model->whereHas('channel', function ($q) use ($user){
                 $q->where('is_hidden', false)
                    ->where(function ($q) use ($user){
                        $q->where('is_private', false)
                            ->orWhere(function ($q) use ($user){
                                $q->where('is_private', true)
                                    ->whereHas('members', function ($q) use ($user){
                                        $q->where('user_id', $user->id);
                                    });
                            });
                    });
            });
```

got and idea from [Eloquent nested WHERE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44054999/eloquent-nested-where-statement)